# How do you create a function progress bar in react?

Tags: reactjs, progress-bar

I have a button in react that when I press it, it simulates an inputted number of roulette games. This is to see how much you can expect to make back from roulette bonuses offered by casinos. Anyway, when the number of simulations is set to a large number like 1000000 simulations, it takes 10+ seconds to complete and display the results. I want to add a progress bar, so for every 1% of the simulations that are completed the progress bar updates to be another 1% completed. This will give the user a better idea of how long the simulation will take, as well as let them know there computer hasn't crashed.

Here is the roulette function, in case you need it...

```
const SimulateEuroRoulette = (starting_balance, wagering, bet_size, simulations) => {
    let results = []
    for(let i = 0; i < simulations; i++){
        let balance = starting_balance
        let wagering_complete = 0
        let bust_out = false
        
        while(bet_size <= balance && wagering_complete < wagering){
            const random_int = random.int(0, 36)
            balance -= bet_size
            if(random_int > 18){
                balance += bet_size * 2
            }

            wagering_complete += bet_size
        }

        if(balance < bet_size && wagering > wagering_complete){ bust_out = true }

        results.push({ balance, wagering_complete, bust_out })
    }

    let bust_out_count = 0
    let balance_total = 0
    let wagering_total = 0
    let simulated = 0
    for(let i = 0; i < simulations; i++){
        if(results[i].bust_out){ bust_out_count++ }
        if(!results[i].bust_out){
            balance_total += results[i].balance
        }
        wagering_total += results[i].wagering_complete
        simulated++
    }

    return { ev: balance_total / simulations, average_wagered: wagering_total / simulations, bust_out_rate: ((bust_out_count / simulations) * 100), simulated }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to refactor your function, so that it updated state variables as it iterates (probably using `useReducer`, as you want to update multiple state variables simultaneously). One of your variables would be the percentage of simulations completed. This would be the variable that you would then tie to the value of your progress bar.

```
<label for="progress">progress:</label>
<progress id="progress" value={state.progress} max="100"> {state.progress}% </progress>
```

In your `reducer`, you probably want logic to only update `progress` when your percentage is a whole number or put in rounding. Don't make your `SimulateEuroRoulette` method reliant on state, just have it `dispatch` your state updates needed. You probably want the function definition to be outside of your component, so you'll need to pass in `dispatch` to call it.